# Is it possible to create (by instantiating a TestFactory) and run tests accross multiple projects with a single gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle

I have `Project A`, `Project B`, and `Project C`, each one deploying a different REST API. I want to smoke test each one after it's deployed to make sure the REST API is working correctly.

By using Rest-Assured and TestNG, I have a `TestFactory` that can create the necessary tests dynamically, reading values from a json that allow me to configure each test suite accordingly. This is working in Project A locally: I have a source set for smoketests and a task that will create and run the tests.

I would like to create a gradle plugin that would allow me to simply run a task and have the tests be created and ran, without having to repeat my testing setup across multiple projects. In other words, I want to share the smoketests across different projects through the creation and usage of a gradle plugin.

So far I managed to run the ´TestFactory´ method through a task from the plugin, but I can't make gradle run the tests after the classes are instantiated. Is this possible at all?

Basically I would like to do something like the following:

```
public class SmokeTestFactoryTask extends Test{

    private static final List<TestingParameter> testingParameters = new ArrayList<>();

    @Inject
    public SmokeTestFactoryTask(String region, String stage) {
        //Neccessary task configurations (I think this is where I need help) 
        //The goal would be to retrieve a List of TestingParameter from which to configure the test class.
    }

    //The end goal is to run this factory from the List, and then have TestNG run the tests it creates
    @Factory
    public Object[] createGetResponseCodeTest() {
        return testingParameters.stream()
                .map(RestAssuredTest::new)
                .toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question looks very good for a first one, however, can you please provide more details about your setup? I use Gradle daily and I don't understand are you having problems with Gradle tasks, Gradle test runners or given test framework (i.e. JUnit 5).

Comment: Thank you! It is a pretty complex problem, which is why I probably can't find any information on this. My issue is with gradle tasks and plugins. Can I have a task created in a plugin that will run a TestNG @TestFactory?

Comment: @LapshinDmitry I have updated the question with some dummy code to exemplify

Comment: Right now it sounds like `java-text-fixtures` builtin plugin can solve your issues: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures.